# keep only keys without None values in dictionary from pandas groups

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5], 
'b': [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,4,1,0,3,0], 
'v': [2,4,3,7,6,5,9,3,2,4,5,2,3]})
>>> df
    a  b  v
0   1  0  2
1   1  1  4
2   1  1  3
3   2  0  7
4   2  1  6
5   3  0  5
6   3  0  9
7   3  1  3
8   3  4  2
9   4  1  4
10  4  0  5
11  5  3  2
12  5  0  3

>>> df.groupby(by =['a', 'b']).v.apply(list).unstack().to_dict('index')
{1: {0: [2], 1: [4, 3], 3: None, 4: None}, 2: {0: [7], 1: [6], 3: None, 4: 
None}, 3: {0: [5, 9], 1: [3], 3: None, 4: [2]}, 4: {0: [5], 1: [4], 3: None, 4: 
None}, 5: {0: [3], 1: None, 3: [2], 4: None}}
```

How can the keys with None values be avoided in the output dictionary? In the present condition, my dictionary ends up 20x bigger than it should just with the needed keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using same idea , just need `to_dict` twice

```
df.groupby(by =['a', 'b']).v.apply(list).groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x : x.reset_index(level=0,drop=True).to_dict()).to_dict()
Out[1092]: 
{1: {0: [2], 1: [4, 3]},
 2: {0: [7], 1: [6]},
 3: {0: [5, 9], 1: [3], 4: [2]},
 4: {0: [5], 1: [4]},
 5: {0: [3], 3: [2]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = df.groupby(by =['a', 'b']).v.apply(list).unstack().to_dict('index')
d = {k: {kk: vv for kk, vv in v.items() if vv is not None} for k, v in d.items()}

# d == {1: {0: [2], 1: [4, 3]}, 2: {0: [7], 1: [6]}, 3: {0: [5, 9], 1: [3], 4: [2]}, 4: {0: [5], 1: [4]}, 5: {0: [3], 3: [2]}}
```

You can also do this in one line if you replace `d` in the second line with your `df` chain.

Answer (score 2):

#### `groupby`

```
{k: d.xs(k).to_dict()
 for k, d in df.groupby(by =['a', 'b']).v.apply(list).groupby(level=0)}

{1: {0: [2], 1: [4, 3]},
 2: {0: [7], 1: [6]},
 3: {0: [5, 9], 1: [3], 4: [2]},
 4: {0: [5], 1: [4]},
 5: {0: [3], 3: [2]}}
```

---

#### `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))

for _, a, b, v in df.itertuples():
  d[a][b].append(v)

d

defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {1: defaultdict(list, {0: [2], 1: [4, 3]}),
             2: defaultdict(list, {0: [7], 1: [6]}),
             3: defaultdict(list, {0: [5, 9], 1: [3], 4: [2]}),
             4: defaultdict(list, {0: [5], 1: [4]}),
             5: defaultdict(list, {0: [3], 3: [2]})})
```