# nested dictionary of groupby indices

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5], 
'b': [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,4,1,0,3,0], 
'v': [2,4,3,7,6,5,9,3,2,4,5,2,3]})
>>> df
    a  b  v
0   1  0  2
1   1  1  4
2   1  1  3
3   2  0  7
4   2  1  6
5   3  0  5
6   3  0  9
7   3  1  3
8   3  4  2
9   4  1  4
10  4  0  5
11  5  3  2
12  5  0  3
>>> df.groupby(by =['a', 'b']).groups
{(2, 0): [3], (5, 0): [12], (3, 0): [5, 6], (5, 1): [11], (1, 0): [0], (3, 
1): [7, 8], (4, 1): [9], (1, 1): [1, 2], (2, 1): [4], (4, 0): [10]}
```

To get a nested dictionary of indices, I am doing:

```
>>> df['idx'] = df.index
>>> {k: {kk: vv for kk, vv in v.items() if vv is not None} for k, v in 
df.groupby(by =['a','b']).idx.apply(list).unstack().to_dict('index').items()}
{1: {0: [0], 1: [1, 2]}, 2: {0: [3], 1: [4]}, 3: {0: [5, 6], 1: [7, 8]}, 4: 
{0: [10], 1: [9]}, 5: {0: [12], 1: [11]}}
```

This is by adapting @piRSquared's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52450398/4974969). 
Is there a more direct way to get to this result?

Comment: You have this line: `x = df.groupby(by =['a','b']).idx.apply(list).unstack().to_dict('index').items()` right? Why not just `dict(x)` then?

Comment: because in that case you're getting all possible combinations of `a` and `b` keys in the nested `dict` with `None` values for those combinations not having anything on `col` `v`, resulting in a `dict` multiple times the actually needed size, which is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: Not sure this is True. Again, didn't run the code but `is None` will catch only if `vv` is `None`, and will not catch `np.nans` for e.g

Comment: but this is the kind of behaviour I am expecting; if there is an `a` - `b` combination, I would want to have its index in the `dict` even if the `v` value is `np.nan`. But if there is not a given combination in my `df` then I woudn't want to have it in my `dict`

Comment: besides, because the values of `x` that you quoted in your original comment are indices, I am not sure how they could end up being `np.nan`s but please let me know if you think otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two `groupby` , I am not sure the efficiency by following solution

```
df.reset_index().groupby('a').apply(lambda x : x.groupby('b')['index'].apply(list).to_dict()).to_dict()
Out[271]: 
{1: {0: [0], 1: [1, 2]},
 2: {0: [3], 1: [4]},
 3: {0: [5, 6], 1: [7], 4: [8]},
 4: {0: [10], 1: [9]},
 5: {0: [12], 3: [11]}}
```

Comment: yes it does do the trick but is 2x slower. I will accept your answer if no other appears soon. Thank you